# list.index returning ValueError when the item is clearly in the list

Tags: python, indexing

I have two copies of a list, one sorted, one isn't, in a dictionary which serve to find the index of any number in the list, starting with the largest. When I print the lists the output is as follows:

```
wealth_comp = {
    'Wealth1': [131, 127, 125, 125, 123, 121, 121, 117, 115, 107, 105, 101], 
    'Wealth2': [127, 125, 121, 117, 105, 121, 107, 123, 131, 101, 115, 125]
}
```

but when I run

```
index = wealth_comp["Wealth2"].index([wealth_comp["Wealth1"][x]])
```

it gives me

```
ValueError: [131] is not in list
```

when it is in the list.

Comment: What is "wealth_comp"?

Comment: There is, indeed, no instance of `[131]` in your list.  All of its elements are integers, not lists themselves.  Get rid of the outer set of square brackets in your parameter to `.index()`.

Answer (score 1):

`[131]` is clearly not in the list. `131` is. So get rid of `[]` brackets.

```
index = wealth_comp["Wealth2"].index(wealth_comp["Wealth1"][x])
```

Comment: One day I'm gonna pay syntax back for all the trouble its caused me, thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
>>>Wealth_Comp = {
                  'Wealth1':131,127,125,125,123,121,121,117,115,107,105,101],
                  'Wealth2':[127,125,121,117,105,121,107,123,131,101,115,125]
                 }

>>> index = wealth_comp["Wealth2"].index(131)
>>> index`
8
```

Cheers